# Should "member for" be "member since"?

Tags: feature-request, profile-page

I am a member of SO for 12 months. I did not receive the yearling batch yet, as the month calculation only is based on months, not on the exact date. But when I looked up my date of joining, statoverflow data dump tells me 08/31/2008, but moderators tell me I joined 09/03/2008. I would like the joining date instead of a wording, just so I know. What do you think?

Comment: was stackoverflow running already on 09/03/2008? :D

Comment: I'm European, so I understand your comment. I lived in the states when I turned 18, on 4/8/xxxx (April 8th), but wanting to have a beer for cheer, I was not allowed, Guess why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like almost every date on our site, just mouse over to see the exact raw UTC date in a tooltip.

This applies to your "member for" field on your /user page as well.

Comment: I never noticed this (on the profile page)! I feel stoooopid. At one point I even ran a manual "halving" search using the "recent activity" page to find it out... oh how embarrassing.