# "Member for" wording on profile page confuses me

Tags: support, profile-page

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should “member for” be “member since”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18665/should-member-for-be-member-since)

When I first accessed my own profile, the heading "Member for" confused me a little bit. It read as "number of days a person can have access to Stack Overflow".

**Member for 1 day**
This makes me think I've somehow managed to create a guest account with limited-period access. But I now know that is not what it means.

**Member since**
This version of the wording reads better to me.

Comment: Nice edit Random, too bad you don't get part of the rep, I didn't up-vote initially because I felt the question was poorly worded.

Comment: That wasn't just a feeling.

Comment: Just had to add that I know you've only been a member of the site for a little over 3 hours. 2009-11-11 06:42:12Z was the time and date you joined.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you put **Member Since**, you have to put a date not a duration for it to make sense.

**Member since 1 day**
**Member since 10th Nov, 2009**

Personally, a duration is a lot easier mentally to digest. Giving this, maybe if you somehow reworded the sentence it is short for (**"This user has been a member for"**) to something that is less ambiguous.

Comment: Honestly, I still believe that a date would be better. If a user has been a member of the site for 3 years, which would look better ?

"Member for 1095 days" OR "Member since 10th Nov, 2009" ?

Comment: OR, as you suggested first: "Member for 3 years"